# WinAPI.GetWindowText для ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую WinApi для получения текста контролов. На комбобоксах не работает, какая может быть проблема? Свойство Text у них вроде бы есть... Может, внутри winapi какие-то подводные камни, о которых стоит знать?

Comment: Если это свойство отображается у вас в конструкторе форм это ещё не значит, что оно есть в комбобоксе Windows который создаётся конструктором. У стандартного Windows контрола такого свойства может и не быть, оно может называться по другому. Штудируйте доки по WinApi  в части стандартых контролов.

Comment: @Alexey действительно, для стандартных контролов в WInAPI есть отдельные функции и каждый из них обладает собственным набором доступных свойств, и описанных в соответствующих структурах того же WinAPI. Можно оформить как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это свойство отображается у вас в конструкторе форм это ещё не значит, что оно есть в комбобоксе Windows который создаётся конструктором. У стандартного Windows контрола такого свойства может и не быть, оно может называться по другому. Штудируйте доки по WinApi в части стандартых контролов